# How to redirect from root URL to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have main view under following URL:

```
 http://wifi.pocc.cnst.com/cnst/#/mapboard/
 |     root               |cntrl|  view   |
```

My goal is when user types in browser: `http://wifi.pocc.cnst.com` to redirect to `http://wifi.pocc.cnst.com/cnst/#/mapboard/` automatically

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might know the mapping of requests to controllers is

`http://your.domain/index.php/controller/method/arg1/../argn`

whereas any request for which no `controller/method/args` segments are given is routed to the default controller.

The default controller is defined in `application/config/routes.php` and you would have to change it as follows:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "my_default_controller";
```

where `my_default_controller` obviously is the controller you have to set up, and therein you set:

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->helper('url'); // might actually not be needed
    redirect('cnst/#/mapboard');
}
```

And if you are using the default controller for other things aswell, you might consider:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->input->server('Request_uri') == '/' and $this->input->server('Http_host') == 'my-host')
    {
        $this->load->helper('url'); // might actually not be needed
        redirect('cnst/#/mapboard');
    }
    // your other stuff
}
```

Or you might actually set a different default controller in the `routes.php` config file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/' and isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) and $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'my-host')
{
    $route['default_controller'] = 'my_special_controller';
}
else
{
    $route['default_controller'] = 'my_normal_controller';
}
```

Voilà.